# Elasticsearch Query: Select documents by comparing lists of values (golang)

Tags: elasticsearch, go

I have a type of document indexed in ElasticSearch, with a simplified structure as follows:

```
{
    id: "54"
    properties: ["nice", "green", "small", "dry"]
}
```

Now I want to select all the documents in this index, which **doesn't** contain a list of given values in the `properties` field.

Something like: `SELECT * FROM index WHERE properties NOT CONTAINS ["red", "big", "scary"]`

How can I implements that on elasticsearch?
(And I someone knows how can I implements such a query on Golang, I'll be even better :-) )

Thanks!

Comment: the golang library github.com/olivere/elastic works well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match those documents from index using the clause `bool`. It will look something like this:

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            { "term": { "properties": "red" }},
            { "term": { "properties": "big" }},
            { "term": { "properties": "scary" }}
         ]
    }
}
```

The query could be like this:

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match": { "id": "54" }
    },
    "filter":{
      "bool": {
        "must_not": [
            { "term": { "properties": "red" }},
            { "term": { "properties": "big" }},
            { "term": { "properties": "scary" }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For more information you can check this link: [Filtered query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html)